# Installing Apache/MySQL/PHP on Mac OS X Snow Leopard without a direct internet connection

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, php, mysql

Are there any good sites that explain the process in such a way that it can be done on a Mac without internet? I would put the installers on a USB drive and move them from an internet enabled machine.

I found this site, but it's a bit much. I'm not up for compiling things...

http://adylitica.com/2009/11/24/installing-amp-apache-mysql-php-on-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard/

EDIT:

I once used MAMP and I didn't like it too much. What about the built in stuff? (which I just discovered via Google.)

edit2: XAMPP works well but I cant seem to get proper permissions for the htdocs folder.
I tried chmod -R -L 775 htdocs and it is not working. I want to be able to dra and drip on finder...

Comment: What didn't you like about MAMP? It's pretty straightforward and easy to use.
PS: I updated my answer.

Comment: @dex - I didn't like MAMP because there's a pro version and a free version. The free version was nagware. I also didn't find that it worked consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html) or [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) if you don't want to compile stuff.

You can copy them to a USB drive and install them to the target host.

Comment: XAMPP worked after I got the permissions set up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [MAMP](http://mamp.info).

Just download the .dmg file, put it on the USB drive and install it wherever you want.

EDIT:
If you don't want to use MAMP, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293484/easiest-way-to-activate-php-and-mysql-on-mac-os-10-6-snow-leopard) answer what you want: Apache + PHP via built in Mac OS X and MySQL installed on the side.

Comment: Beat me to it. MAMP and MAMP Pro are very simple and easy to set up.